# how to find index of element in C with recursion

Tags: c, list, indexing, element

i have this, it checks if element is in list or not, but how get the index of element ?

```
// function that check if element is in list
int checklist(struct list *my_list, int n) {
  while (my_list != NULL) {
    if(my_list->info == n) return 1;
    my_list = my_list->next;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is the code, i mistakenly poster other one

Comment: int checklist (struct list *my_list,int n)
{
    while (my_list != NULL) {
    if(my_list->info == n) return 1;
    my_list = my_list->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the right code instead.

Comment: Did you want to use recursion? Or is your title just wrong?

Comment: yes, i want to do it using recursion if possible

Answer (score 3):

Use additional variable to remember the current index:

```
int checklist (struct list *my_list,int n) {
int i=0;
while (my_list != NULL) {
 if(my_list->info == n) return i;
 my_list = my_list->next;
 i++;
 }
return -1; 
}
```

or

```
int checklist (struct list *my_list,int n) {
int i;
for (i=0;my_list != NULL; i++, my_list = my_list->next) 
 if(my_list->info == n) return i;
return -1; 
}
```

By the way your code has nothing to do with recursion, i think its called linked list.

Comment: No problem, just tag one of the answers if its sufficient so other members of community will see that this question is already solved.

Answer (score 2):

Use an additional argument to the function which carries the index you're currently looking at. Though you need a way to return it: return -1 if the list is exhausted and the index of the first found item otherwise.

P.S. I don't see any recursion here.